# "+::::::" at the end of /etc/passwd

Tags: passwd

In some of my servers there is this strange line at the end of `/etc/passwd/` consisting of just:

> +::::::

Does anyone knows what it means?

I searched the net but only found the same, unanswered question by one Jim from 2012:

> Anyone know what this means in Linux SLES 11 and can it be removed

(see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/).

Servers in question run `SLES 12`, the other `Ubuntu bionic`.

Comment: Did you already see this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106215/whta-does-bin-bash-in-etc-passwd-mean?

Comment: Lukas, thx for the pointer! I think this answers it. It really seems to be NIS specific, because since I removed the line I cannot login (via NIS). Lol.

Comment: Dear God, people are still using NIS? That's scary.

Comment: It used to be useful for earlier LDAP databases too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I hear you, but there's still nothing that does what NIS did without the associated problems, **and nothing else besides**.  So it gets used because there's still no simple replacement for it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton My thought exactly, but I still come across libraries which default to using it until pummelled into panting submission. Also I suspect that the nsswitch.conf file goes back to that era, and that's still "bery much a thing".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm reposting the below from the following Unix stackexchange answer:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106215/whta-does-bin-bash-in-etc-passwd-mean

The answer lies in the nsswitch.conf(5) man page:

> Interaction with +/- syntax (compat mode)
>
> Linux libc5 without NYS does not have the name service switch but does
> allow the user some policy control. In /etc/passwd you could have
> entries of the form +user or +@netgroup (include the specified user
> from the NIS passwd map), -user or -@netgroup (exclude the specified
> user), and + (include every user, except the excluded ones, from the
> NIS passwd map).
>
> You can override certain passwd fields for a particular user from the
> NIS passwd map by using the extended form of +user:::::: in
> /etc/passwd. Non-empty fields override information in the NIS passwd
> map.
>
> Since most people only put a + at the end of /etc/passwd to include
> everything from NIS, the switch provides a faster alternative for this
> case (passwd: files nis) which doesn’t require the single + entry
> in /etc/passwd, /etc/group, and /etc/shadow. If this is not
> sufficient, the NSS compat service provides full +/- semantics. By
> default, the source is nis, but this may be overridden by
> specifying nisplus as source for the
> pseudo-databases passwd_compat, group_compat and shadow_compat. These
> pseudo-databases are only available in GNU C Library.

Answer (score 12):

As Lukas Räpple pointed out in the comments, that line is a legacy entry for using NIS with ancient libc5.

If you want to keep using NIS but remove that line, change the `passwd: compat` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to `passwd: files nis` first. You should also check the `shadow:` and `group:` lines (and `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` files) for similar legacy settings.